# In Vector Calculus and Curvature, is the Normal just the tangent of a tangent?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, curves, curvature

And because it is infinitesimally small, a normal vector becomes the inward facing vector?

For example a parametric function $\vec{r(t)=\langle{}x(t), y(t)\rangle}$

- it's tangents are $\vec{r(t)}= \langle{}x'(t), y'(t)\rangle{}$. Take it's unit vector so we only consider direction, not scale. Thus: $\vec{r(t)}_{unitVec}= \langle{}x'(t), y'(t)\rangle{}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y(t)^2}}$

To find the normal, take the tangent of the unit vector $\vec{r''(t)}_{unitVec}=\vec{r(t)}_{Normal}=$ Normal Vectors of $\vec{r(t)}$.

- where $\frac{\vec{T'(t)}}{||\vec{T'(t)}||}=N$, is the unit normal?

Is this line of thinking correct?

This then can be divided by arc length to get Curvature like so: $\frac{\vec{r(t)}_{Normal}}{MagnitudeOfCurve'sTangent}\rightarrow \frac{\vec{r(t)}_{Normal}}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y(t)^2}}=\frac{||d\vec{T}||}{||d\vec{S}||}=\frac{||\frac{d\vec{T(t)}}{dt}||}{||\frac{d\vec{S(t)}}{dt}||}=k$

Drawing below to be verified, technically, tangent of tangent is at the end but because it is infinitesimally small, it stems from the same point?.. Is that right?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arthur for pointing it out, changed!

Answer (score 1):

the curvature of a curve is defined in differential geometry as the coefficient $k$ of the unit normal.

So if you have

$T'(t)=kN$

Then $k$ is the curvature.

in general if you have a unit vector

$x(t), ||x(t)||=1, \forall t$

then

$x(t)\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(x(t)\cdot x(t))}{dt}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d||x(t)||^2}{dt}=0$

Comment: Thank you. Firstly, I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Is the normal just the tangent of the (unit) tangent($\vec{T}'(t)=N$)?... //Secondly, I don't get where that half came from. Here: $x(t)\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(x(t)\cdot x(t))}{dt}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d||x(t)||^2}{dt}=0$

Comment: $k=||T'(t)||$ The half comes from differentiation: $\frac{d(x(t)\cdot x(t)){dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot x+x\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$